# RecyclerView class not found in Eclipse

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, android-recyclerview

I tried to add `RecylerView` in my layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecylcerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecylcerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But there is this error:

> The following classes could not be found:
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecylcerView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML,
>   Create Class)

[image]

I have Done:

1. RecyclerView library project in my eclipse
2. mark as library project
3. android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar add to build path
4. check for import/export
5. Then I added this library to my project.
6. Refresh and Clean project.

But the error remains.

Note : "Please reply for Eclipse, not for Android Studio"

Comment: Do use Android Studio instead Eclipse

Comment: @Akashsingla19 Please accept [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30002567/635549)

Comment: Run App , Its Working < Add ID To RecycleVIew And Use it < Attach The Adapter < I Dont Now Why But For Me Working !

Comment: He had the reference name wrong. he had _RecylcerView_.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to `C:\Users\Hk-PC\Desktop\eclipse\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\recyclerview-v7\22.1.1`
2. Open `recyclerview-v7-22.1.1.aar` file with Winrar.
3. There is a jar file named `classes.jar`. Copy that to your project libs folder.
4. Right click `classes.jar`, add to build path.

That's it. It worked for me. Hope it works for you too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  While this may have solved your own problem, it is not related to the problem asked.  the answer is a typo and has already been given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30002567/635549)

Answer (score 2):

It's supposed to be `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` not  `android.support.v7.widget.RecylcerView`. that's the reason the error is occurring.

Comment: Instead of `RecyclerView` he had _RecylcerView_

Answer (score 0):

Have you compiled and used RecyclerView in an actual emulator or android phone? I think this is a problem with the rendering library . It happens the same to me in Android Studio.

Comment: Whenever I run, I got 05-02 04:04:20.095: E/AndroidRuntime(2783): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.RecylcerView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.lolipopdemo-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
05-02 04:04:20.095: E/AndroidRuntime(2783):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)

Answer (score 0):

You will import Recycler view as a project in to your workspace by going to \android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\recyclerview and Chcek By going to Its Properties android that it is marked as library or not if nor mark it as library  add it in to your project As Library by going to project properties add .

If you have Done this thing then open Android sdk And Check that ndroid support Library Version should not Be 21 as it has some bug so update it to  version 22.

Comment: I have updated version 21 to 22, But error is showing.

Comment: Do one thing make a new fresh project and check if this error i still their or not then tell.

Comment: I have made 3 new projects for this purpose, But error is still showing

Comment: Delete the android-support-v7-recyclerview.jar from the build path.